# How to initialize random without time

Tags: c, random, srand, psoc

I am programming a microcontroller (PSoC5), which doesn't have a system time.

What is the best way to generate a seed to initialize [srand](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)?

TIA

Comment: `1` more than used last time? *Everytime you use `srand()` you could read/update a file with the seed.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the chip has ADCs, one option is to take advantage of noise picked up on the ADCs.  Basically, you can take a few reads of the ADCs, then bitwise AND to keep the least significant bit.  Then use the all of the least significant bits sampled to generate your seed.

Comment: I like the idea, I try it out later and accept your answer

Comment: this is how `/dev/random` is implemented.  It reads the random input from different sources and combines it.

Comment: @alinsoar Nice tip.  Thanks.